# How to delete (or select) specified rows or columns of ff matrix, or to subset ff matrix?

Tags: r, ff, ffbase

A ff matrix of 300,000 rows and 1000 columns:

```
x <- ff(1: 100000000, vmode = "integer", dim = c (300000, 1000), dimorder = c (2,1))
```

I want to delete the last line of the matrix use the command:

```
x[-300000,]
```

However,I got the error: "can not allocate vector of size 1.1 Gb", it seems that `x[-300000,]` is no longer returned ff object , but directly stored in the memory of all. So I have two questions :

1. How to delete the i-th row ( or column ) of the matrix x in, and then still return ff object.
2. how to select the rows or subset of which the j-th column equals 100 (an integer), and then still return ff object.

Maybe the functions `ffwhich` and `subset.ff` in `ff` package could help me, but I do not understand how to use them.